# Как скомпелировать код python под Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, windows-7, pyside2

Есть код который написан на `Windows 10 x64`, как его скомпелировать для работы под `Windows 7 x32`?

P.s использую библиотеки `Pyqt5`, `Pyside2`, `docxtmpl`, `datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я компилировал на виртуалке, где стоит win7x32, потом просто перетаскивал файлик.

Вообще, я читал, что Майки что-то переделывали в 10тке и программы, скомпилированные на ней не пойдут на 7рке, зато программы скомпилированные на 7рке идут на 10тке.

Решение гуглил очень долго, но так, кроме этого костыля, и не нашел.

[image: Проблема]

Comment: Чего сразу минусовать то? Это один из вариантов,пускай и костыльный. Я долго изучал эту тему, но решения, кроме как этого, не нашел.

Comment: не мой минус. Можно и как вы сделали. Хотя можно поставить python x32 и скомпилировать. Но, там куча проблем будет.

Comment: Ну, а что поделать?

Answer (score -1):

Установи python 32bit. Установи в него библиотеки 32bit. Установи "компелятор" 32 бит и компилируй в 32бит.

Comment: КомпЕлируй!! ☝️